# Return Zero if input value is NaN

Tags: javascript, math, reactjs, nan

Is there a best way to prevent `NaN`? I have number input field that whenever I clear the field, I get `NaN`.

```
_amount: function(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  var newValue = (value === NaN ? 0 : value); // Thought this could work
},

<input type="number" value={this.state.amount} onChange={this_amount} />
```

Now in my render I have `400 - this.state.amount`. The things is, when I clear the input field, amount state is `null`. How to prevent this? Is it possible that when I clear the field I get zero? Say I type in `3` then clear the field, `NaN` pops up.

Thanks

Comment: @DavidS Not really.

Comment: Really, Sylar? You don't think anyone has asked how to check a number is NaN in JavaScript before?

Comment: Im intrigued about this website, Stack overflow, and most of its users. I've noticed that bullies love to prey on noobs. Those bullies are the ones that downvotes without thinking. Yes I should have researched but I forgot. Maybe a notice to say to research first?? Damn Could I deleted the post? No! Because an answer was already given.

Comment: You seem to be taking these downvotes too personally. The downvote button is for, among other things, poorly researched questions. That is why it exists. It's not meant to "bully" you. You are not a victim, you're just some guy who asked a question without trying to answer it first.

Comment: @DavidS, considering @Sylar's question is [clearly] in reaction to having a React state management bug I think it's perfectly fine. A little guidance would be more helpful. e.g. using falsey evaluation would be a useful hint - `value={this.state.amount || 0}`

Comment: @BradGreens - absolutely concur - I've been writing react a while and just ran into a similar problem.  BTW, coercing the value to zero in case of a falsy input yields a crappy UX where there's a zero you can't delete.  I instead used `value={this.state.amount || ''}` where coercing to an empty string means you can delete the number all the way - FWIW

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> `NaN`is never equals to anything including `NaN` itself hence rely on [**`Number.isNaN(value)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) method.

```js
_amount: function(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  var newValue = (isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);

  //OR sorthand as `NaN` is falsey
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value) || 0;
}
```

### The necessity of an `isNaN` function

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (`==` and `===`) to determine whether a value is `NaN` or not, because both `NaN == NaN` and `NaN === NaN` evaluate to false. Hence, the necessity of an `isNaN` function.[[*Ref*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description)]

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way I found was

```
var number = (yourVariable || 0)
```

Because `NaN` is a falsey value, this will return 0 whenever `yourVariable` is NaN.

A way to check, if a number is NaN or not is to use the `isNaN` function.

```
isNaN(yourVariable); // Returns true is yourVariable is NaN
```

Side note:

The above method can be used for multiple problems too. For example: getting a value from an array (wich may not exist) and getting a value from a 2d array.

Getting value from array:

```
yourArray[i] || 0
```

Where `i` is the id you want to access

Getting value from a 2D array:

```
(yourArray[i] || [])[j] || 0
```

Where `i` and `j` are the position of the element in the array

Comment: `0||0` also returns `0` so this isn't exclusively a test for `NaN`

Comment: @evan058 I don't think I understand that

Comment: The OP asked for a way to return `0` if the input is `NaN`. Your suggested test would return `0` if the input is `NaN` or `0` which is not exactly what they asked for.

Comment: It would be giving a false positive when the input is `0`

Comment: @evan058 See, returning 0 instead of 0 is kind of the same case...

Comment: I see, so in the restricted case where you want replace a `NaN` with a `0`, it works ok because you would be replacing `0` with `0`. But I am saying that it also silently replaces any "falsy" value with `0`, including `NaN`, `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `""`

Comment: @evan058 He knows, that the current value should be a number

Comment: That's it. I wanted to return a number: `0` when there is a `NaN`.